# Survey 123 Exporting to Excel - Labels

Tags: arcgis-survey123-connect

I'm able to export the survey results into Excel without any issues. But I'm looking for a way to export the Labels rather than the Names of the fields.

Right now, when I export my results, the headers in my Excel shown as the Names of the field.

I can manually fix that, but I'm looking for a way to directly export the field Labels from the survey results into excel.

Below is an example from my survey form - when I export the results, the results are exported using the Name column for each field.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: @Hornbydd thanks for the comment. I modified the question.